# Export more .swf Files with AS3 Code

Tags: actionscript-3, export, flash, flash-cs5

I have a little animation in my Flash Professional, and I need this animation more than 200 times with different text on it. The text is already dynamic, in a for loop. What I want is to create a loop which creates the .swf with the different text. So I only execute it once, and it creates more than 200 .swf files automatically. Is that possible?

Comment: It is theoretically possible, but highly impractical. Why do you want to do that ? There may be a better solution than that.

Comment: I want to do that, because if a little thing changes in my animation, I have to export it again for 200 times...

What is a better solution?

Comment: Why don't you use Flashvars to set the dynamic value of the text ? That way, you don't have to generate 200 swf. Only one, which would be loaded with different parameters. Flashvars can even be set directly in the swf url, if needed.

Comment: uff I never worked with that, can you please give me a short example how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having 200 swf files, maybe you should try having only one swf file, and use a Flashvar to define which text you want to display.
Here is a quick sample on how to do this, and how to use this.

In the Flash code, you'll have something like that :

```
// var myTextField:TextField; // in this sample, I want to set the content of myTextField 
// here, I am using an Object as an associative Array. Thus, I can do textTable[''] to obtain 'text sample 1'
var textTable:Object = {
  label1 : "text sample 1",
  label2 : "foo bar",
  showError : "some error occured",
  pizza : "I love pizza"
  // [...]
}

// I'm fetching the flashvars in params, and then specifically the content of the labelKey Flashvar.
var params:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
var key:String = params.labelKey;

// I'm getting the text that correspond to the given key, and set myTextField with it.
var label:String = textTable[key];
if (label != null) {
  myTextField.text = label;
}
```

If you load the swf in HTML, you'll have something like that in the HTML :

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="550" height="400" id="main">
  <param name="movie" value="main.swf" />
  <param name="FlashVars" value="labelKey=label2" /><!-- Flashvar : we set labelKey to 'label2' - the swf will show "foo bar" -->
  <embed src="main.swf" width="550" height="400" autostart="false" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" FlashVars="labelKey=label2" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```

If you don't, and only use the URL, it will look like that :

```
http://my.domain.com/main.swf?labelKey=label1
or
http://my.domain.com/main.swf?labelKey=showError
or
http://my.domain.com/main.swf?labelKey=pizza
```